# How can I resize a table or div when clicking in Angular 2?

Tags: css, typescript, html-table, angular2-template

Does anyone know how to resize a table or div when click on a button or somewhere in angular 2?
I trying to resize a table width: 300px to 100px when clicking on a function that using CSS and typescript.

```css
table{
  width: 300px;
  resize: horizontal;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```js
doResize(): void {
        document.getElementById("table").style.resize = "100px horizontal";
    }
```

html

```html
<div class="resizeTable">
      <table id="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price($)</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>BH12</td>
            <td>Shirt</td>
            <td>300</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
 <button click="doResize()"> Rezise </button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest is to use a property in your component to set a css class. Here is an example where the property large in your component is used to control which class is applied to your table:

CSS:

```
table {
  resize: horizontal;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.large {
    width: 300px;
}

.small {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Html, here you bind to the property large in your component:

```
<table id="table" [class.large]="large" [class.small]="!large">
</table>
```

Component:

```
export class AppComponent {
    large: boolean = true;

    doResize(): void {
        this.large = false;
    }
}
```